# Stream live videos

Tags: python, ubuntu, video, stream, live

How can I stream a live movie or video for my clients to connect to a webpage and watch? I would prefer that it's in a SWF form, so maybe I could load a file into the SWF. This isn't a webcam type of thing, like maybe if I want to stream a video I made a while ago and allow my users to watch it all at once, and not have it restart every time they refresh. Could this be done in Python, PHP, etc? Or does it involve a program? I am using Ubuntu for my dedicated server. I also need the audio to be live too.

Thanks

Comment: I'm using VLC (called from inside a Python script using subprocess) to grab the video and dumping it into an mp4 (although it's not exactly what you want, maybe it'd give you an starting point)

Answer (score 0):

"stream a live movie or video" and "stream a video I made a while ago" are contradictory, what do you really mean by "live"? Are you referring to a "broadcasted video" (i.e. may be prerecorded, but everyone will be viewing from the same stream) or "live video" (i.e. viewing events as it happens, being live implies broadcast).

There are services like [Justin.TV](http://www.justin.tv/) or [Ustream.TV](http://www.ustream.tv/) that allows you to broadcast vieo stream from either live cameras, live screen capture, and/or prerecorded videos. They have their own (flash-based or HTML5-based) web players that can handle live streams and you will need to use their broadcasting software to manage the live stream. There is also Youtube Live if you are a Youtube partner.

Comment: I mean broadcast a video and allow viewers to view the same stream. I don't want it to be a prerecorded webcam video, I mean any video. For example, if I wanted to let my viewers watch a video from YouTube, or something that I downloaded from a website, I want to be able to broadcast it for the users to watch at the same time.